# Django signals - kwargs['update_fields'] is always None on model update via django admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-signals

I have a signal inside my django app where I would like to check if a certain field in my model has been updated, so I can then proceed and do something.

My model looks like this...

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    tax_rate = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    display_price = models.PositiveInteger()
    inputed_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

My signal looks like this...

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Product)
def update_model(sender, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs['instance']
    if 'tax_rate' in kwargs['update_fields']:
        # do something
```

This returns the error `None` is not an iterable. I have read the django signal documentation regarding the `update_fields` and it says `The set of fields to update as passed to Model.save(), or None if update_fields wasn’t passed to save().`

I should mention that I am working inside django admin here so what I hoped would happen is, I could create an instance of my Product model in django admin and then later if the value of tax_rate or price were updated, I could check for those and update the `list_price` accordingly. However, `kwargs['update_fields']` always returns None.
What am I getting wrong? Or is there some other way I could achieve that result inside django admin?

**Updated section**

Now, say I introduce a field called `inputed_by` in my product model, that points to the user model and I want that field populated when the model is first saved. Then another field `updated_by` that stores the user who last updated the model. At the same time I wish to check whether either or both the `tax_rate` or `price` has been updated.

Inside my model admin I have the following method...

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    update_fields = []
    if not obj.pk:
        obj.inputed_by = request.user
    elif change:
        obj.updated_by = request.user

        if form.initial['tax_rate'] != form.cleaned_data['tax_rate']:
            update_fields.append('tax_rate')
        if form.initial['price'] != form.cleaned_data['price']:
            update_fields.append('price')

    obj.save(update_fields=update_fields)
    super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

My signal now looks like this...

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Product, dispatch_uid="update_display_price")
def update_display_price(sender, **kwargs):
    created = kwargs['created']
    instance = kwargs['instance']
    updated = kwargs['update_fields']
    checklist = ['tax_rate', 'price']

    # Prints out the frozenset containing the updated fields and then below that `The update_fields is None`

    print(f'The update_fields is {updated}')

    if created:
        instance.display_price = instance.price+instance.tax_rate
        instance.save()
    elif set(checklist).issubset(updated):
        instance.display_price = instance.price+instance.tax_rate
        instance.save()
```

I get the error `'NoneType' object is not iterable`
The error seems to come from the line `set(checklist).issubset(updated)`. I've tried running that line specifically inside the python shell and it yields the desired results. What's wrong this time?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The set of fields should be passed to `Model.save()` to make them available in `update_fields`.

Like this

```
model.save(update_fields=['tax_rate'])
```

If you are creating something from django admin and getting always `None` it means that `update_fields` has not been passed to model's `save` method. And because of that it will always be `None`.

If you check `ModelAdmin` class and `save_model` method you'll see that call happens without `update_fields` keyword argument.

[image]

It will work if you write your own `save_model`.

The code below will solve your problem:

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        update_fields = []

        # True if something changed in model
        # Note that change is False at the very first time
        if change: 
            if form.initial['tax_rate'] != form.cleaned_data['tax_rate']:
                update_fields.append('tax_rate')

        obj.save(update_fields=update_fields)
```

Now you'll be able to test memberships in `update_model`.

Comment: This is not quite complete, the real deal here is getting the content of `update_fields`, for that you will have to mess with the `post` request when you hit the button `save` in order to detect the forms fields that has been changed.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda no need to touch `request` data, check the edit.

Comment: I've made updates to my question. Could you please have a looksie.

Comment: Remove the last line in save_model method. Super will trigger signal again. No need to do that you’re saving object in the line above.

Comment: With just the `obj.save(update_fields=update_fields)`, when you first add an item, I get the success message but it doesn't appear in the list view. That is if you omit `super().save_model`

Comment: This would cause problem since you overriding the save function on the admin model itself, you need to check other conditions that using the save_model()

Answer (score 7):

To add to Davit Tovmasyan's post. I made a more universal version that covers any field change using a for loop:

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 
    ...
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        update_fields = []
        for key, value in form.cleaned_data.items():
            # True if something changed in model
            if value != form.initial[key]:
                update_fields.append(key)

        obj.save(update_fields=update_fields)
```

EDIT: **WARNING** This isnt actually a full solution. Doesnt seem to work for object creation, only changes. I will try to figure out the full solution soon.

Comment: Just curious, have you been able to find a full solution? I'm having issues with one field being m2m

Comment: just added the full answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75616692/4984493

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to add an alternative that relies on the pre_save signal to get the previous version of the instance you're evaluating (from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843747/get-previous-value-of-a-field-in-post-save-signal)):

```py
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Product)
def pre_update_model(sender, **kwargs):
    
    # check if the updated fields exist and if you're not creating a new object
    if not kwargs['update_fields'] and kwargs['instance'].id:
        # Save it so it can be used in post_save
        kwargs['instance'].old = User.objects.get(id=kwargs['instance'].id)


@receiver(post_save, sender=Product)
def update_model(sender, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs['instance']

    # Add updated_fields, from old instance, so the method logic remains unchanged
    if not kwargs['update_fields'] and hasattr(instance, 'old'):
        kwargs['update_fields'] = []
        if (kwargs['update_fields'].instance.tax_rate != 
                kwargs['update_fields'].instance.old.tax_rate):
            kwargs['update_fields'].append('tax_rate')

    if 'tax_rate' in kwargs['update_fields']:
```

### comparing to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54579134/4470542)

#### Disadvantages

- Extra query on every save that doesn't have `update_fields` (if you're not opening Django Admin to the world, this shouldn't be problematic)

#### Advantages

- Don't need to override any method or class
- You only need to implement the logic for the fields you want to evaluate, and they are in the same method, so no excuse for mistakes ;)

If you're doing this for many classes, you should probably look at other solutions (but the accepted answer is also not perfect for that!)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.

```
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if change:
            obj.save(update_fields=form.changed_data)
        else:
            super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone who is coming in!

I believe this is the **complete** solution to this case, **note that** if you have any **ManyToMany** fields in your model **then you should skip adding them to update fields**

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        """
        Given a model instance save it to the database.
        """
        update_fields = set()
        if change:
            for key, value in form.cleaned_data.items():
                # assuming that you have ManyToMany fields that are called groups and user_permissions
                # we want to avoid adding them to update_fields 
                if key in ['user_permissions', 'groups']:
                    continue
                if value != form.initial[key]:
                    update_fields.add(key)

        obj.save(update_fields=update_fields)
```